# LCM Challenge Range Query

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

I am trying to solve this question [LCM Challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codex-15-0/challenges/lcm-challenge).

How can modulo be used when values of LCM goes quite high or what is the best approach for the question ?